# ADC Hat with 8 differential channels and 24 bit resolution for 100 - 200 SPS (Hz)

Tags: hardware, analog-to-digital, hat

I'm sorry if there's a similar post, I could not find it (them).

As the title implies, I'm looking for an ADC hat for the Rapspberry Pi 3 Model B with 8 differential channels to sample up to 200 SPS (or 100SPS if there is not 200SPS option).
All options I've seen go up to 20 SPS, or I can increase it but at resolution cost (It becomes 22 bit, 20bit, 16 bit, etc).

I have been looking for this for about one week with no luck!

Thank you very much!

JM

Comment: Shopping suggestions are off-topic.

Comment: @joan [Are](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40/should-questions-about-peripherals-or-accessories-be-allowed?noredirect=1&lq=1) [they](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121/should-we-adopt-stackoverflows-policy-of-disallowing-recommendation-questions)?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev But please note that the following is off topic : Asking for specific purchasing recommendations.